# $M_1$ is compact if and only if $M_2 = (A,d_2)$ is a complete metric space whenever $d_2$ is equivalent to $d_1$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M_1 =(A,d_1)$ be a metric space. Then $M_1$ is compact if and only if $M_2 = (A,d_2)$ is a complete metric space whenever $d_2$ is equivalent to $d_1$.

I am finding difficulty in proving this please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completeness and Topological Equivalence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193152/completeness-and-topological-equivalence).  This is the more difficult direction.  For the easier direction, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258931/in-a-metric-space-compactness-implies-completness?rq=1 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467279/prove-that-a-compact-metric-space-is-complete?rq=1